# How do I get half of the formula to the bottom line?

Tags: equations, subequations

```
\begin{equation}
    Y(z) =  H(z)H(z^{-1})X(z) = (h(1)+h(2)+ ...+ h(n+1)z^{-n})(h(1)+h(2)+ ...+ h(n+1)z^{n})X(z)
\end{equation}
```

I wrote the equation like this. but I want to get the bottom line after the second equals. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `align` instead, then alignment points are marked using `&` and you start a new row via ``\\``. `equation` does not support line breaks. Please note that this sort of thing should be covered by any decent latex introduction.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below:

```
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    
    \begin{document}

%%If you need the equation number center to both of the equations    
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        Y(z) &=  H(z)H(z^{-1})X(z)\\
             &= (h(1)+h(2)+\cdots+ h(n+1)z^{-n})(h(1)+h(2)+\cdots+ h(n+1)z^{n})X(z)
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
    
%%If you need the equation number second line of the equations    
    \begin{align}
        Y(z) &=  H(z)H(z^{-1})X(z)\nonumber\\
             &= (h(1)+h(2)+\cdots+ h(n+1)z^{-n})(h(1)+h(2)+\cdots+ h(n+1)z^{n})X(z)
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `align` and an additional line break in the last part, in case it doesn't fit within the text width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    Y(z) &=  H(z)H(z^{-1})X(z)\nonumber\\
         &= (h(1)+h(2)+\cdots+ h(n+1)z^{-n})\nonumber\\
         &\quad\cdot(h(1)+h(2)+\cdots+ h(n+1)z^{n})\cdot X(z)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```